# Unable to visualize label in donut chart - D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, donut-chart

I'm trying to plot a donut chart using d3, based on these two examples:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193
http://jsfiddle.net/ragingsquirrel3/qkHK6/

However, I can't see the labels of the data.
Here can be found a minimal example:

https://jsfiddle.net/g6vyk7t1/

I'm wondering what I'm missing.

```
jsonArr = [{
  "label": "13",
  "value": 13.17435599605977
}, {
  "label": "11",
  "value": 10.599857294624265
}, {
  "label": "16",
  "value": 16.06213289774901
}, {
  "label": "14",
  "value": 13.511044375821099
}, {
  "label": "11",
  "value": 10.664713102997277
}, {
  "label": "15",
  "value": 14.563786284297807
}, {
  "label": "16",
  "value": 16.00697524769618
}, {
  "label": "14",
  "value": 14.359596161811186
}, {
  "label": "16",
  "value": 16.30948044715333
}, {
  "label": "12",
  "value": 11.667434335739946
}, {
  "label": "9",
  "value": 8.906828269284498
}, {
  "label": "12",
  "value": 12.184727712259644
}, {
  "label": "29",
  "value": 28.91564471677896
}, {
  "label": "15",
  "value": 14.794540561843725
}, {
  "label": "7",
  "value": 6.75160611562344
}, {
  "label": "15",
  "value": 15.200055092907874
}, {
  "label": "41",
  "value": 41.432547293738104
}, {
  "label": "12",
  "value": 11.871964986439362
}]

var colorrange = [
  "#7f3b08",
  "#a50026",
  "#d73027",
  "#f46d43",
  "#fdae61",
  "#fee090",
  "#ffffbf",
  "#ffffff",
  "#e0f3f8",
  "#abd9e9",
  "#74add1",
  "#4575b4",
  "#4575b4",
  "#d8daeb",
  "#b2abd2",
  "#8073ac",
  "#542788",
  "#000000"
];


data = jsonArr;

var width = 300,
  height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(colorrange);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var svg = d3.select("#info").attr("align", "center").append("svg")
  .attr("class", "piechart")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  });

g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return d.data.label on line 122.  The label is under the data object.

```
g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.label;
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/g6vyk7t1/1/

Comment: That is how the layout works.  You provide the data you want, and then you provide the accessor function to pull that value from your data: function(d) { return d.label;}  However, when you access the node's content as built by the layout, the value is the arc specific data and your data is encapsulated within the data property of that object (where your label happens to reside).